# How to fix - ERROR [django.security.SuspiciousFileOperation:216]?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am getting following error while running Django 1.9.x on Mac OS

```
[26/Nov/2016 07:33:23] ERROR [django.security.SuspiciousFileOperation:216] 
The joined path (/static/fonts/DINLight.ttf) is located outside of the base path 
component (/Users/petermac/python27/erpproject/app/staticfiles)
```

My settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'basic_files')

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_BASEDIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uncollectedstatic')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  STATICFILES_BASEDIR,
)

STATIC_HOST = os.environ.get('DJANGO_STATIC_HOST', '')
STATIC_URL = STATIC_HOST + '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Templates
TEMPLATE_DIR = join(STATICFILES_BASEDIR, 'templates')
```

What should I do to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the environment variable `DJANGO_STATIC_HOST` is not defined, as `os.environ.get('DJANGO_STATIC_HOST', '')` is returning `''`. When you then do `STATIC_URL = STATIC_HOST + '/static/'` (by the way, I think you should use `os.path.join` for that, as you do in the previous lines), you are getting just `/static/...` which is probably not what you want. Recheck your `DJANGO_STATIC_HOST` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! Should I update like following: STATIC_URL = os.environ.get('STATIC_HOST', '/static/')

Comment: Depends on whether you have initialized STATIC_HOST or not. Also, the fallback value (`/static/`) will not work, unless you have a `/static` folder in your filesystem, which I guess it's not the case.

Comment: The app was installed on Heroku and working there with existing settings but same settings is not working while deployed the app on my local env. I have followed the link http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#make-sure-staticfiles-is-configured-correctly as a guidance but could not find anything about changing for local env.

Comment: I see, so Heroku is setting the environment variable for you. For local development of course you have to either set it manually (use `export DJANGO_STATIC_HOST=<your URL>` in the console before running `runserver` or just initialize the variable directly. The whitenoise developers however recommend falling back to Django's development static file server: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development Maybe you should consider that, it should be a simpler way to have access to the files.